# How can I release a lock on a file in Linux without killing the process

Tags: virtualbox, file-locking

Oracle VirtualBox is holding one of the disk files. I want to release the lock on the file without having to kill the process or deleting the file. Is it possible?

Here is the output of lsof:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE     SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
VBoxSVC 2935 vbox   23r   REG   8,35 253360058368 12976130 /home/vbox/VirtualBoxVMs/virtm0/virtm0-disk1.vdi
```

Comment: Thanks Mayur Bhangale, it worked out. Unfortunately I still can't vote for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FD = 23r meaning file descriptor 23 and it was opened for reading.

gdb tool can be used to release lock on this file

```
    gdb -p $PID
    p close($FD)

    eg:

    gdb -p 1737
    .....
    (gdb) p close(6)
    $1 = 0
    ...
    Quit anyway? (y or n) y
    Detaching from program: /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2, process 1737
```

Hope this helps.